# How to draw this particular diagram in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Can anybody help me to draw this diagram in latex?

[image]

```
\begin{figure*}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cXX@{}}
%
\begin{tabular}{cc}

   & \subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Image}}\\
\subfloat[C]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}} 
   & \subfloat[D]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Image}}\\

   & \subfloat[F]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Image}}\\
\end{tabular}
&

\subfloat[G]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}


&
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[H]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}\\
\subfloat[I]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}
\end{tabular}

\end{tabularx}

\caption{Many figures}\label{foo}
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: result B]

Solution usint Ti*k*Z and `\includegraphics` directives inside of `node`s. The `image` is `\includegraphics`d is an external file, of course. See p.182 and onwards for more information on Ti*k*Z arrows if you want to change the arrow style (I used `stealth` here -- others are available, if so desired).

You can either compile the `standalone` pdf:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{path-to-standalone.pdf}
    \caption{my fancy diagram}
    \label{fig:fancy_diagram}
\end{figure}
```

or remove the preamble (and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}) of my solution (and add the`\usetikzlibrary` directives to your main preamble, of course),

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{mytikzpicture.tex}
    \caption{a caption for the fancy drawing}
    \label{fig:my_fancy_drawing}
\end{figure)
```

As for the actual diagram itself:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        textnode/.style={
            draw,
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split horizontal,
            rectangle split parts=2,
        }
    ]
    \path (0, 0) node (a) {\includegraphics{image}}
          (2,0)  coordinate (ab)
          (4, 2) node (b) {\includegraphics{image}}
          (4, 0) node (c) {\includegraphics{image}}
          (4,-2) node (d) {\includegraphics{image}}

          (7, 2) node[textnode] (e) {Text \nodepart{two} Text}
          (7, 0) node[textnode] (f) {Text \nodepart{two} Text}
          (7,-2) node[textnode] (g) {Text \nodepart{two} Text}

          (9,0) coordinate (fj)

          (4, 4) node[draw] (h) {Text}
          (7, 4) node[draw] (i) {Data (Text)}
          (10, 0) node[draw] (j) {Text}

          (11  ,4)  node (k) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}
          (10.5,3.5) node (l) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}
          (10.0,3.0) node (m) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}

          (11  ,-3.0) node (n) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}
          (10.5,-3.5) node (o) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}
          (10.0,-4.0) node (p) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}}

          (13,3) node[draw] (q) {text}

          (10,-6) node[draw,minimum width=2cm] (r) {text}
    ;

    % Stealth is the arrow style. Other options: >, latex, etc.
    \draw[-stealth] (a)  -- (c);
    \draw[-stealth] (ab) |- (b);
    \draw[-stealth] (ab) |- (d);

    \draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (b) -- (e);
    \draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (c) -- (f);
    \draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (d) -- (g);

    % place arrows midway-ish
    \begin{scope}[decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{latex}}
        },
        shorten <= 3pt,
    ]
        \draw[postaction=decorate] (e) -| (fj);
        \draw[postaction=decorate] (g) -| (fj);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[-stealth,shorten <= 3pt,shorten >=3pt] (f) -- (j);

    \draw[-stealth,shorten >=3pt] (m) -- (j);
    \draw[-stealth,shorten <=3pt] (j) -- ($(p) + (0,2.0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As always with TeX, there are many possibilities for doing things differently and/or better, but it's a start.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But the problem is if I change the images I need to manually adjust the arrows. Is there any other alternative way to adjust automatically? Instead of adding regular text how do add a caption for overlapped images?

Comment: @LIsa Terribly sorry for the delay -- real-life events intervened and I didn't have much time in the past few weeks to spend online. I presume you've solved/circumvented this problem by now, but just in case not, you could try the `capt-of` package. You can then use a `\captionof{figure}{...}` command instead of `Text`. I'm not entirely sure how well this approach would work though, or if it might not make more sense to rethink the overall approach. Again, sorry for the delay.